# Hide custom field if empty

Tags: customization, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I'm displaying values from a custom taxonomy on single pages of my custom post type.

I have a custom post type "artwork" with a taxonomy "artists". How I display the artist name on the single post page (or multiple artists names if multiple artists are assigned to the post). If no artist is assigned to the post, no artist is shown on the page. That works fine.

```
<?PHP //  ARTIST(s) attached to Artwork

    $artists = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'artists' );
    $artistsArray = array();

    if( ! empty( $artists ) ) : 
        echo "<div>Artist: <strong>";
        foreach ( $artists as $artist ){ 
            $artistsArray[] = '<span><a href="/artists/'.ucfirst($artist->slug).'">'.ucfirst($artist->name).'</a></span>';
        }
        echo implode( ', ', $artistsArray );
        echo "</strong><div>";  
    endif; ?>
```

In my artists taxonomy, I have custom field "artist instagram". Further down on the single blog post, I have a link that leads to the instagram account of the artist.

```
<?php
    $artistigs = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'artists' );
    if( ! empty( $artistigs ) ) : ?>    
    <?php foreach( $artistigs as $artistig ) : ?>                   
        <div><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> <strong><a href="https://instagram.com/<?php the_field('artist-instagram', $artistig); ?>" target="_blank">@<?php the_field('artist-instagram', $artistig); ?></a></strong></div>
    <?php endforeach; 
    endif;
?>
```

The link is displayed correctly. But I want to hide it when an artist has no instagram. I'm using `if( ! empty() )`, but it's still showing the link if an artist's instagram field is empty. Why?

Thank you for your help!

---

EDIT UPDATE:

With this code, the Instagram link only shows up on posts assigned to artists with an IG link (as desired). The problem: It only outputs `$artistig` and all other text/HTML within `foreach`is ignored (e.g. the TEST text is not put out).

```
<?php 
    $artists = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'artists' );
    if( !empty( $artists ) ) :  
        foreach( $artists as $artist ) :        
            $artistig = the_field( 'artist-instagram', $artist );
            if( !empty( $artistig ) ) : 
                echo "IG User TEST: ". var_dump( $artistig ) ." END TEST";
            endif;      
        endforeach;
    endif; 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not running check on whether the artist's instagram field is empty, you're running a check on whether the 'artists' term is empty, which it isn't.

```
<?php
    $artistigs = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'artists' );
    if( ! empty( $artistigs ) ) : ?>
         //This will execute if the artist term is not empty
    endif;
?>
```

I don't use ACF myself so not 100% sure how stuff like `the_field()` works but try this:

```
<?php
    $artists = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'artists' );
    if( !empty( $artists ) ) : ?>    
    <?php foreach( $artists as $artist ) :
        $artistig = get_field( 'artist-instagram', $artist );
        if( !empty( $artistig ) ) :
            echo '<div>';
                echo '<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> <strong><a href="https://instagram.com/' . $artistig . '" target="_blank">@' . $artistig . '</a></strong>';
            echo '</div>';
        endif;
   endforeach; 
  endif;
?>
```

================

**UPDATE**

To address your update, the `var_dump()` is really going to mess with formatting, so lets just remove it.

```
<?php 
    $artists = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'artists' );
    if( !empty( $artists ) ) :  
        foreach( $artists as $artist ) :        
            $artistig = get_field( 'artist-instagram', $artist );
            if( !empty( $artistig ) ) : 
                echo 'IG User TEST: '. $artistig .' END TEST';
            endif;      
        endforeach;
    endif; 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works in general, as the value is only displayed on posts from artists with an Instagram account. But the output is only the value of the custom field – all text and HTML within foreach is ignored.

Comment: That may be something about ACF... ...maybe we need to try just echoing everything?

What is the output if you `var_dump( $artistig );`?

Comment: I wasn't able to manage it yet. I posted an update with the new code in the original post. This only puts out the `$artistig' value but ignores the test text.

Comment: Remove the var_dump() and just leave the . $artistig .

Comment: Same problem. This only puts out the `$artistig` value, but not the text/HTML. :(

Comment: Is the site live or is there somewhere I could take a look?  This is weird.  I don’t see a reason why it would just ignore everything else.

Comment: I found the error. It must be `get_field` instead of `the_field`. Now it works. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  I've used ACF a couple of times when working on existing sites, but I don't regularly.  Glad it's all working for you.  :-)